# An error has occurred while opening external DTD - 400 Error

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, dtd

I'm having an issue where a third party dtd is intermittently throwing a HTTP status 400 error when I am trying to validate xml.

The error thrown is:

> An error has occurred while opening external DTD 'http://example.com/fake/path/MyDTD.dtd':  Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request).
> at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
> at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.PushExternalEntityOrSubset(String publicId, String systemId, Uri baseUri, String entityName)
> at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.DtdParserProxy_PushExternalSubset(String systemId, String publicId)
> at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.DtdParserProxy.System.Xml.IDtdParserAdapter.PushExternalSubset(String systemId, String publicId)
> at System.Xml.DtdParser.ParseExternalSubset()
> at System.Xml.DtdParser.ParseInDocumentDtd(Boolean saveInternalSubset)
> at System.Xml.DtdParser.Parse(Boolean saveInternalSubset)
> at System.Xml.DtdParser.System.Xml.IDtdParser.ParseInternalDtd(IDtdParserAdapter adapter, Boolean saveInternalSubset)
> at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDtd()
> at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDoctypeDecl()
> at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
> at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
> at System.Xml.XmlValidatingReaderImpl.Read()
> at MyApi.Infrastructure.Serializers.MyCustomXmlSerializer.ValidateAgainstDtd(String xml, Boolean throwOnFailure)
> in D:\a\1\s\src\Infrastructure\Serializers\MyCustomXmlSerializer.cs:line 198

And here is my method for validating xml:

```
public bool ValidateAgainstDtd(string xml, bool throwOnFailure = false)
{
    var messages = new List<string>();

    try
    {
        var settings = new XmlReaderSettings
        {
            ValidationType = ValidationType.DTD,
            DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse,
            XmlResolver = new XmlPreloadedResolver(new XmlUrlResolver())
        };

        settings.ValidationEventHandler += (sender, args) => messages.Add(args.Message);

        using var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml));
        using var reader = XmlReader.Create(stream, settings);

        while (reader.Read()) { }  //this is line 198 in the exception
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        messages.Add($"DTD Validation Exception: {e.Message}{Environment.NewLine}{e.StackTrace}");
    }

    if (messages.Count == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }

    if (throwOnFailure)
    {
        throw new CustomXmlSerializationException(messages.ToArray());
    }

    return false;
}
```

I'm not getting any other validation errors, and the model we are serializing is common between several different calls, but it only fails for one call and only intermittently - that same call works in some other instances.

The same code works fine in integration tests run as part of an Nunit suite on a local dev machine, but when we deploy the code into our stage environment we suddenly get intermittent issues with pulling back the DTD.

Comment: Error 400 means the server did not accept your request.  Which means you did not get a valid xml in the response.  You should not try to deserialize an xml when you get a 400 status.  Only deserialize when you get a 200 ok.  Your intermittent issue is with the connection to the server failing intermittently.

Comment: That was my first thought, but the third party I am working with says they reviewed logs on their end and see no connection failures.  I'm beginning to wonder if I could be triggering a defensive measure in cloudflare (their host) with a sudden influx of requests.

Comment: A server can return any status it wants (even if it is wrong).  Then vendor code is reporting the wrong error if the connection completed.  Or your code is going to a different application.  It is possible you are going through a proxy and the proxy is creating the error.  But if you were going through the proxy than no message would be seen in the log files.  Have vendor check if there is any record in the logs at the time you failed.  The time is important.

Comment: I have integration tests using the exact same code that work fine.  They validate and get data without issue.  However, it is when I use a .NET core (6.0) API around the code that it fails in all environments - locally and in our azure environment.

Comment: Your error is caused by the contents of the xml file.  All your code is doing is reading the xml file so I agree it is not the code.  The issue could be the xml file and/or the version of Core you are using.  This could be an error that was fixed in later version of Core 6.0.  I would declare the XmlReader at beginning of code and then put a break point inside the exception.  Then when the error occurs you can examine the XmlReader to see what line the exception is occurring.

Comment: I can take the contents of the XML and send them directly to the third party server and get back results.  I can use an integration test calling through the exact same code and get results.  I rewrote the underlying layer to not use flurl and use an HTTP client directly - same error.  It is ONLY when the code is called via the context of our .net 6 API that it fails.  Meanwhile other calls to the same endpoint with different payloads work just fine.

Comment: Error may be due to resolver.  See : https://www.jardinesoftware.net/tag/net/